# Find the biggest value of $|a-b|+|b-c|+|c-a|$ when $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Given that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1$
How can I prove that the maximum value of |a - b| + |b - c| + |c - a| is $2\sqrt{2}$ ?
In extends, given that $a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2 + ... + a_{2020}^2 = 1$ find the maximum value of $|a_1 - a_2| + |a_2 - a_3| +|a_3 - a_4| + ... + |a_{2020} - a_1|$

Comment: What contest is this from? Apparently, it is still ongoing?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen hello, this came from a math contest last year in my country (Vietnam).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality, assume that $a\geq b\geq c$. Then:

$$|a-b|+|b-c|+|c-a| = 2(a-c)$$

And we have:

$$
\begin{aligned}
(a-c)^2&=2(a^2+c^2)-(a+c)^2\\
&\leq 2(a^2+c^2) \\
&\leq 2(a^2+b^2+c^2)\\
&=2
\end{aligned}$$

Therefore $2(a-c)\leq 2\sqrt{2}$. Equality occurs when $(a,b,c) = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 0,-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$.